# Button in UpdatePanel not firing Click event: RequiredFieldValidator the cause

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I'm working on a page that consists of Telerik RadToolTip, an UpdatePanel that contains a Button, and a few user controls.  There is also a Master Page, which is where the ScriptManager is located.

Previously, I had a RadAjaxManager on the Master Page and RadAjaxProxyManager.  I removed them and began to implement standard Update Panels because of complexities within the User Controls.

Now, however, I can't seem to get any of this page to behave as expected. When I place a Button in the UpdatePanel, I expect a Partial Postback and I expect the Button's OnClick event to be fired. However, when I run this code with a breakpoint in the btnPostBack_Click event code, the breakpoint never gets hit.

If I cut and paste the same controls with the same settings into a new project, the breakpoint gets hit.  Is there something in the environment of the site or could Telerik be interfering with the Button's Click event?  I've removed all RadAjaxManager/Proxies.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AV.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="AssetView.aspx.cs" Inherits="AV_ASP_UI.AssetPages.AssetView" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="AssetDiagram" Src="~/Controls/AssetDiagram.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="AssetInfo" Src="~/Controls/AssetInfo.ascx" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function DoPartialPostBack(command, id) {
            document.getElementById("<%= hfldId.ClientID %>").value = id;
            document.getElementById("<%= btnPostBack.ClientID %>").click();
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfldId" runat="server" />

    <telerik:RadToolTip ID="RadToolTip1" runat="server" Modal="true" ShowEvent="FromCode"
        Position="Center" RelativeTo="BrowserWindow" HideEvent="FromCode" TargetControlID="hfldFireToolTip">        
    </telerik:RadToolTip>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btnPostBack" runat="server" Text="Button" style="visibility: hidden" OnClick="btnPostBack_Click"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlWorkArea" CssClass="pnlWorkArea" runat="server" Height="770px" onMouseDown="hideSVGTtip(event);">
        <uc:AssetDiagram ID="ucAssetDiagram" runat="server" CanvasHeight="720" CanvasWidth="276" />
        <uc:AssetInfo ID="ucAssetInfo" runat="server"/>
    </asp:Panel>
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Does it work without the RadToolTip?

Comment: That would be very difficult to determine. But if I don't have a better idea soon, I'm going to have to try it.

Comment: Rather then attempting to remove the radToolTip, I'm going to rebuild the page, adding in functionality until I find out what breaks the bahavior.

Comment: Ok, I found it. I'd love for someone to tell me why. One of the UserControls that is NOT in the updatepanel had a RequiredFieldValidator. When I remove the RequiredFieldValidators, the UpdatePanel works as expected.

Comment: All validators on the page would usually be in effect when a button attempts to submit the form. You need to set ValidationGroups to get different fragments of the page to validate separately. You can also set the CausesValidation property of a button to false, but it will still post your entire page even if there is invalid input, so you need to account for this should you take this path.

Comment: That does make some sense. Appreciate the info.